# SQL testing a foreign key using a query on oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (
        Employee_ID number(8),
        Employee_Name varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT pk_EmployeeID PRIMARY KEY(Employee_ID));

CREATE TABLE Drivers(
        Driver_ID number(8) NOT NULL,
        Employee_ID number(8) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT pk_DriverID PRIMARY KEY (Driver_ID),
        CONSTRAINT fk_EmployeeDataTwo FOREIGN KEY (Employee_ID) REFERENCES Employees(Employee_ID));
```

How can I use a query to call using the foreign key in drivers to check it's name on the employee list? E.g.

```
select employee_name 
from employees 
inner join drivers on employees.employee_name = drivers.employee_name;
```

Which doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

You need to change join condition to use `Employee_ID` column:

```
select employee_name 
from employees 
inner join drivers on employees.Employee_ID = drivers.Employee_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use columns which connects two table on join condition

```
Select employee_name from employees
İnner join drivers on employees.employee_id= drivers.employee_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work though just changing the syntax from other answers:

```
select employee_name 
from employees e
inner join drivers d 
where e.employee_id = d.employee_id;
```